# Iteration Push Alternative Javascript

Tags: javascript, array-push

Obviously, this is not allowed in javascript:

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    array[i].push(data[i].name);
}
```

Does anyone know of a workaround that does the same thing?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you provide `data` variable and be more explicit on what you want to do?

Comment: It has been answered @Gothdo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    array[i] = [];
    array[i].push(data[i].name);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zv0xfzzs/

Comment: doesn't this just makes lots of little arrays, each consisting of 1 name? I am NOT saying its wrong, but trying to understand the outcome. Thx

Comment: @gavgrif That is correct. But that is what the Alexey wants looking at his code.

Comment: @gavgrif Yep. This works perfectly.

Comment: I guess I am just trying to understand the desired outcome and why all the names can't be pushed into one array and accessed from that.

Comment: @gavgrif the reason is because the way my data coming out needs to have the same format as the data coming in.

Answer (score 0):

but Alexey Ayzin, shurely this is the better alternative - create a single array, push the desired values into it and then access it via normal means::

```
arrayTest = [];
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      arrayTest.push(data[i].name);
}
```

This will give arrayTest all names, and can be accessed as:

```
var testName=arrayTest[3];
```

Doing it the other way will give you lots of unnamed arrays - how are they to be used?